# Android manifest activity disappeared

Tags: android, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have a problem when I try to build or run my Android app.
I restored my project (after some others bugs), I removed and I added again Android platform.
Everything in Android manifest seems correct: activity, permission, service.
If I run “ionic cordova run android --device” the android manifest is recreated but It’s not the same !!!

How is it possible ? Can I run/build without recreate android manifest ?
That’s is very important because otherwise I got activity not found error in some situations.

Answer (score 0):

It was a custom edit-config in config.xml that was breaking my rebuild. I removed it and it seems to work well now.